# MongoDBcompound Index

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 queries in MongoDB on the 1st query I have 2 fields and on a second query, I have 5 fields. 2 fields are same like 1st query so I have to create 2 compound index or I can add all fields in one index?

Comment: Please share your code snippets so that you can get precise answers.
You need to be careful when using indexing. you don't want to create too many indexes and you don't want to create only a few indexes. it has to be in the middle.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_covered_queries.htm

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/covered-query-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

One index will do the job for your two queries, if the two common fields are the first indexed fields. Let's take an example :

```
query 1 : {A:"AA",C:"CC"}
query 2 : {A:"A", B:"BB", C:"CC", D:"DD",E:"EE"}

index : {A:1, C:1, B:1, D:1, E:1} will cover both queries
index : {A:1, B:1, C:1, D:1, E:1} will cover only second query
```